# Python: ImportError of my own module

Tags: python, python-2.7

`Error: ImportError: No module named common_components.modules.logging.logger` happens when running `python emailsender.py`.

Output:

```
(dev) me@xxx:~/workspace/python/python/common_components/modules/email$ python emailsender.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emailsender.py", line 23, in <module>
    from common_components.modules.logging.logger import Log
ImportError: No module named common_components.modules.logging.logger
```

Not sure whether something wrong with the following project structure:

```
(dev) me@xxx:~/workspace/python/python$ tree
.
├── common_components
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── email
│   │   │   ├── emailsender.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── logging
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── logger.py
└── __init__.py
```

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
(dev) me@xxx:~/workspace/python$ python python/common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py", line 23, in <module>
    from common_components.modules.logging.logger import Log
ImportError: No module named common_components.modules.logging.logger
(dev) me@xxx:~/workspace/python$ cd python/
(dev) me@xxx:~/workspace/python/python$ python common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py", line 23, in <module>
    from common_components.modules.logging.logger import Log
ImportError: No module named common_components.modules.logging.logger
```

Comment: `common_components` is not in your python path. The most easy way to solve that is to run your script from `.` with `python common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py`. The working dir is always in the python path.

Comment: Your `python` directory has `__init__.py` in it. Not sure if that makes a difference, but it does seem strange as I imagine you don't intend it to be a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python adds the current directory to the `PYTHONPATH`, but your current directory is `~/workspace/python/python/common_components/modules/email`.

Fix this either by running from `~/workspace/python/python/`:

```
me@xxx:~/workspace/python/python$ python common_components/modules/email/emailsender.py
```

Or by setting `PYTHONPATH` manually:

```
me@xxx:~/$ set PYTHONPATH=~/workspace/python/python/

me@xxx:~/workspace/python/python/common_components/modules/email$ python emailsender.py
```

Comment: You need to execute from the `workspace/python/python` directory so it can find the `common_components` package. You're executing from `workspace/python` which has the `python` directory in it, not `common_components`.